# JSONB subset of array

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, activerecord, jsonb

I have the following JSONB field on my `posts` table: `comments`.

`comments` looks like this:

```
[
{"id": 1, "text": "My comment"},
{"id": 2, "text": "My other comment"},
]
```

I would like to select some information about each comments.

`SELECT comments->?????? FROM posts WHERE posts.id = 1;`

Is there a way for me to select only the `id` fields of my JSON. Eg. the result of my SQL query should be:

```
[{"id": 1}, {"id": 2}]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`jsonb_to_recordset`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/functions-json.html) to split each comment into its own row.  Only columns you specify will end up in the row, so you can use this to keep only the `id` column.  Then you can aggregate the comments for one post into an array using `json_agg`:

```
select  json_agg(c)
from    posts p
cross join lateral
        jsonb_to_recordset(comments) c(id int)  -- Only keep id
where   p.id = 1
```

This results in:

```
[{"id":1},{"id":2}]
```

[Example at db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bKMfq1FNEsBaaipouJibFJ/4)

Answer (score 1):

You may use `json_build_object` + `json_agg`

```
select json_agg(json_build_object('id',j->>'id'))
from  posts cross join jsonb_array_elements(comments) as j
where (j->>'id')::int = 1;
```

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=e330f53a05063db544d4087760f1ad5b)